# are there osmf concepts for scheduled live events?

Tags: osmf

Lots of ancient, non-negotiable history due to mergers and acquisitions, so I realize there are better ways to do all of this, however... I am faced with the following:

I have an osmf based video player where a particular playlist item (for a live video), must do the following:

1. play a preRoll prior to displaying a countdown
2. display a countdown until the video start time (synched with the server time)
3. play another preRoll prior to video playback
4. play the live stream until the server time reaches the stream end time
5. then play a post roll video

I've gotten this working for the most part, but I'm running into walls with the arbitrary insertion of "ads", since I don't want to trigger events associated with loading new media.  If I try to inject a new ad (particularly after the stream has played), the live stream will display again.  While I could figure out some horrible way to make this work, I just wanted to make sure first that I'm not missing something critical about osmf and live events.  I'm also a bit uncertain as to what is native osmf in the architecture I'm working with and what is homegrown.

1) Does osmf have a concept for a scheduled live event that might make this easier

2) Does osmf have an option to arbitrarily insert a video into playback based on some external call without changing the playlist index or returning to the beginning of the video.

Comment: Did you solve this? How did you get the ads to work on OSMF? I'm using an OSMF based player called StrobeMediaPlayback and it's a real pain getting ads to work

Comment: we did it outside osmf and created our own playlist manager that created interstitial video players.  It ended up being pretty disruptive to our architecture so I don't have anything clean or worth writing about unfortunately.  As far as help with the ads, sounds like you might want to post your question in its own thread? :)